# Limiting text overflow depending on size of container

Tags: css

I'm trying to work on a container a lot like http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/ 's main posts page. The text fills it's space (which changes depending on how many lines the title takes up) but I can't get it working without overflow: hidden cutting text midway or text flowing out of the container.

Comment: Please explain your problem a little more. Are you wanting the container to grow based on how long the title is?

Comment: Yeah, if the title is only 1 line then the text below should fill an extra line, and if the title is 2 lines the text should be 1 line less so no matter what length either are, they fill the container nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple components to this solution; it involves both CSS and jQuery.

---

### HTML:

I started off by putting wrapping each cell in a `<cell>` tag, which is custom defined as an inline-block element. Inside that element are two more elements, `<t>`, which holds the title, and `<cnt>` which holds the content.

```
<cell>
    <t>Title</t>
    <cnt>Content</t>
</cell>
```

---

### CSS:

- The cell container is an `inline-block` element of size 300x200 (this can be resized freely).
- The t element is a block element with automatic height and forced line-height. (The  line-height should be the same as the font-size)
- The cnt element is a block element with hidden overflow and similar forced line-height (again it should match the font-size)

This is reflected in the following CSS:

```
cell
{
    text-align: left;

    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}

cell t
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
}

cell cnt
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

### jQuery

The height of the content has to be set by jQuery because there is no way to force the content to be a certain size without knowing the size of the title, which changes.

I start off by getting the height of the whole element, the height of the title, and the line height of the content. By subtracting the height of the title from the height of the element, I get the allotted height for the content.

Then, by dividing it by the line height and casting it to an integer, we get the number of lines that will fit in the space. Finally, multiplying the number of lines by the line-height gives the total height of the content.

Since the content has hidden overflow, it is forced to remain inside the height we set for it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("cell").each(function(){
    
        var cellHeight = parseFloat($(this).css("height"));
        var titleHeight = $(this).find("t").height();
        var lineHeight = parseFloat($(this).find("cnt").css("line-height"));
    
        //Calculate height
        var nHeight = cellHeight - titleHeight;
        var numLines = parseInt(nHeight / lineHeight);
        nHeight = numLines * lineHeight;
    
        $(this).find("cnt").css("height", nHeight);
    
    });

});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgQne/3/)